# In the PAW-method how does one come up with the most general form for the projector functions?

Tags: projector-augmented-wave

The projector augmented-wave (PAW) method as introduced by [Blöchl](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.50.17953) gives an expression for the most general form for the projector functions
$$\tag{1}
\langle \tilde{p}_i \vert = \sum_j \left( \lbrace \langle f_k \vert  \tilde{\phi}_l \rangle \rbrace \right)_{ij}^{-1} \langle f_j \vert,
$$
"where $\vert f_j \rangle $ form an arbitrary, linearly independent set of functions". This statement is given without any further detail.

My assumption so far is that this satisfies the condition $\langle \tilde{p}_i \vert \tilde{\phi}_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$. Thus I have tried to plug it in but I can't show the relation. I am confused about several things:

- Is the summation index $j$ the same one as the one of $\tilde{\phi}_j$ in the orthonormality relation?
- I take it that the indices $ij$ denote a matrix element and the power of $-1$ denotes the inverse. Then where does the condition of linear independence for $f_j$  come into play?
- Is this even the right track?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that this part is key:

> My assumption so far is that this satisfies the condition $\langle \tilde{p}_i \vert \tilde{\phi}_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

To make the notation a bit simpler, let's define $S$ as the matrix with
$$
S_{ij} = \langle f_i \vert  \tilde{\phi}_j \rangle\tag{1}.
$$
Its inverse matrix is $S^{-1}$. The expression for the projectors is then
$$
\langle \tilde{p}_i \vert = \sum_j (S^{-1})_{ij} \langle f_j \vert,\tag{2}
$$
such that

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \tilde{p}_i \vert \tilde{\phi}_j \rangle 
&=\sum_k (S^{-1})_{ik} S_{kj} \tag{3}\\
&= (S^{-1} S)_{ij} \tag{4}\\
&= \delta_{ij}.\tag{5}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Beautiful! In eq. 3, the sum should go over $k$, right?

Comment: Yes! Fixed, thanks